# Javascript return false behavior what's the deal?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I am loading an html page with a basic script and a basic form.  However when the page loads there are two radio buttons the user can select, YES or NO.  If you the user selects neither, I would like to present an alert box.  I successfully present the alert box, but when the user clicks the "okay" button within the alert box the user is redirected to a different page.  I added the statement, *return false;* in hopes that this wouldn't happen.

The code is as follows,

```
<!-- Javascript radiobutton form validation -->

<script type="text/javascript">

function valForm(form) {

    if(!document.getElementById('splash_false').checked && !document.getElementById('splash_true').checked  ) {
        alert('You either like splash pages or dislike em, choose one ...please');
        return false;
    }
}

</script>

<!-- Javascript radiobutton form validation END -->


</head>

<body>
<img src="pics/DSCN1566-300x225.jpg" alt="" width="640" height="auto"  />
<h1>Hello Javascript redirection.</h1><br />

<p>
<form name="tosplashornottosplash" action="splash-process.php" method="post">
Splash pages are stupid.

<input type="radio" name="splash" id="splash_false" value="false" /> No
<input type="radio" name="splash" id="splash_true" value="true" /> Yes

<input type="submit" name="splashSubmit" onClick="return valForm(tosplashornottosplash)" value="Enter" />
</form>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your handler in the form's `onsubmit` callback

```
<form onsubmit="return valForm(this)" action="splash-process.php" method="post">
```

Returning false to the onsubmit handler will prevent your form from being posted

Answer (score 1):

Try to make it an onsubmit-callback on the form, instead of an onclick-callback on the button. That way, returning `false` will stop the form from posting.

**Side note:**

Since you don't seem to use the reference to the form in your callback, there is no need to pass it to the callback function. So you could just as well call it like this, from the onsubmit-attribute on the form:

```
onsubmit="return valForm()"
```

And get rid of the the `form` variable in the callback signature:

```
function valForm() {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind to the `form`'s `onsubmit` event:

```
<form onsubmit="return valForm()">
```

(Note that the `form` parameter in your `valForm` function was never actually used nor was it properly filled in either. The `return valForm(tosplashornottosplash)` referred to an non-existant `tosplashornottosplash` JavaScript variable and thus evaluated to `undefined`.)

However it's recommended that you bind your event handlers in the JavaScript code itself instead of wiring them in the HTML markup:

```
document.getElementById("myform").addEventListener("submit", valForm, false);
```

This assumes you gave your `form` the ID `myform` and that this code is executed *after* the `form` element is loaded into the DOM. You can ensure this by putting your JavaScript at the bottom of the page (just before closing `body`) or by binding to the `DOMContentLoaded` event of the `document`.

To support older IE browsers as well, you need to use `attachEvent` when `addEventListener` is not available. [The article on addEventListener at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) suggests something like:

```
if (form.addEventListener) {
  form.addEventListener("submit", valForm, false);
} else if (form.attachEvent)  {
  form.attachEvent("onsubmit", valForm);
}
```

Alternatively, you can throw [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in which facilitates DOM selection (e.g. `$("form[name=myform])"`) and takes care of the cross-browser compatibility issues for you (e.g. `$.on('submit', valForm)`).

Comment: Worth noting that older versions of IE doesn't support `.addEventListener` but uses `.attachEvent` instead. [Further reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener)